# CLion 2018.2 using 100% CPU (per debug session) while debugging

Tags: c++, clion, lldb

CLion 2018.2 pegs 100% CPU (1 core) while debugging and stopped at a breakpoint even when Power Saver is turned on.  This continues even after execution has stopped, as long as the debugger is still open (e.g. after a failed assertion).

Eventually the CPU usage goes down, but if I cmd-tab back to clion and then back away from it, CPU again goes to 100% again for an extended period of time.

If I have 2 debug "sessions" going on, it takes 200% cpu (3 = 300%).  As soon as I "terminate" the debugging, the CPU goes to 0%.

I'm using "bundled lldb" "version 6.0" in CLion.  Trying to use "bundled gdb" gives "command timed out" after sitting at 100% and never even starting to run my program.   Running the system lldb from the command line on the same program does not reproduce the CPU utilization.  Mac is running 10.13.6.  Memory usage is high, but memory pressure is still in the "green" in Activity Monitor.

Anyone seen anything like this?

[image: cpu graph]
CPU Graph (Just look at steady state first half)

CLion process sample (very long): https://gist.github.com/xaxxon/7f8a1b413bdc1af55da5de522ce9052d

Comment: Sometimes even when you write code the CPU usage can be over 100%.

Comment: @GoingMyWay the point is that it shouldn't be doing anything at all - CPU should be at 0%  It shouldn't be doing anything other than waiting for the user to ask it to do something.

Comment: Yeah, the same issue occurred on my MacBook.

Comment: @GoingMyWay That's why I said "even when Power Saver is turned on" in my question...

Comment: @xaxxon if you find a solution please share it. I'm using CLion on Linux and CLion takes 100% or close to it when all I am doing is code editing. Even when I am not using CLion and it is open in the background it is taking all my resources. I am using CLion version 2018.2.3

Comment: I haven't seen this in a while... sometimes switching debugger (gdb->lldb or lldb->gdb and then back helped I think)